# Paging in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, pagination, html-table

In MVC 5, how to create paging for table? The following is a table structure.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
           Item ID
        </th>
        <th>
           Item Name
        </th>
        <th>
           Rate
        </th>
        <th>
          Stock
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)
        </td>
    </tr>
}    
</table>
```

Comment: Why not use the build in webgrid it will  create the table with paging for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. Using webgrid, we can achieve the paging

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemMaster>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Item Details";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model,rowsPerPage:5);
}
<h2>Item Details</h2>
@grid.GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 7):

I recommend the PagedList package which is available on nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList

**Here is the full documentation**

https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: I couldn't download the pagedList via nuget it shows the following error Install-Package : Unable to find package 'PagedList.Mvc'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  PagedList.Mvc
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: You are trying to install PagedList.Mvc package instead of PagedList.

Comment: I have run the following statement in the nuGet console. "Install-Package PagedList.Mvc". But it shows the error

Comment: The command should be **Install-Package PagedList** PagedList and PagedList.MVC are different packages. PagedList.MVC has a dependency on PagedList that why you get the error

Answer (score 4):

This tutorial has a good explanation of paging and how to install and use the packages:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

**Grid.MVC** is an open source and working Grid with **sorting and paging**

(and unlike telerik you do not need to change anything on controller side just add reference in your view and use.)

To install nugget package ([Install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc/))

```
PM> Install-Package Grid.Mvc -Version 3.0.0
```

In your view you can auto-create columns as below **(or customize see [User Guide](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start&referringTitle=Home))**

```
@using GridMvc.Html

@Html.Grid(Model).AutoGenerateColumns()
```

**See [Online Demo](http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can look for DataTables jquery plugin [here](https://datatables.net/). It is a very powerful and light weight plugin that supports sorting and searching inside the table.